# Xpath selection using non-standard html custom attribute

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I'm using python with lxml to pull data out of html.

I'd like to select from HTML that uses non-standard attributes in the html.

E.g.:

```
content = '''
<html>
<body>
    <div id="one">content</div>
    <div nonstandardattr="somevalue">custom attribute text node</div>
</body>
</html>
'''
```

I'd like to do something like this:

```
page = html.fromstring( content )
page.xpath( '//div[@nonstandardattr="somevalue"]/text() ' )
```

Where page is an instance of lxml.html.HtmlElement.

When I try that, I see the following exception:

```
XPathEvalError: Invalid predicate
```

Comment: It looks like you're missing a closing bracket in your xpath string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
//div[@nonstandardattr="somevalue"]/text()
```

Try the above. The closing `]` was missing

Xpath doesn't differentiate non standard html attributes from standard ones since xpath views html as xml, which means anything goes as far as defining syntactically valid attributes.